# How can I show that a subset of a group generates the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In general, how can I show that a subset of a group generates the group?/ some subgroup is generated by some elements of the group?

In particular, I want to show that $SL(2,\Bbb F_3)$ is the subgroup of $GL(2,\Bbb F_3)$ generated by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$, assuming that I know that $SL(2,\Bbb F_3)$  has order $24$. I have absolutely no idea where to begin with. I dont want to list out $24$ distinct elements of $SL(2,\Bbb F_3)$ though because that is stupid.

Comment: This question is taken from Abstract Algebra, 3rd Edition: Dummit & Foote, where the authors assure the readers that we can safely assume the subgroup $SL(2,\Bbb F_3)$ has order 24, which we'll prove later in the book.

Comment: What is the order of $A$ (and of $B$)? What is the order of $AB^{-1}$? These questions already take you half the way...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen $|A|=|B|=3$ and $|AB^{-1}|=6$. How does this help? And why would sb. think of computing $|AB^{-1}|$ in the first place...

Comment: $A$ and $B$ generete a subgroup $H$. Which is its order? It must divide 24. There is an element of order $6$ and an element $AB$ of order $4$. Since the order of an elements must divide the order of the group $H$, the order of $H$ can be 12 or 24.

Comment: Suppose now it is 12, then since there are 4 3-sylows (because A and B are already two different elements of order 3, and the number of 3-sylows is 1 module 3 and divides 12/3=4), 9 elements are already taken, we have only 3 more elements, we need to put an element of order 4 which needs 3 slots, and we miss the order 6 element. There is not enough space if the group has 12 elements, so $H$ has 24 elements and thus is the whole subgroup.

Comment: Hmm... I guess we dont need any Sylow theorems. Since $|A|=|B|=3$, $|AB|=4$ and $|AB^{-1}|=6$, I think I can list out at least 13 distinct elements and complete the proof. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be the two matrices given in the question.

$|A|=|B|=3$, Also it is easy to see $|AB|=4$ and $|BA|=4$, and observe that $AB$ and $BA$ generate different groups.

Call the group generated by $A$ and $B$ over the field $F_3$ be $G$

Clearly, from above , we have $12|$Order($G$)

Note that $G$ is a subgroup of $SL(2,F_3)$ as determinant of any element of $G$ is $1$ and so the order of $G$ can be $12$ or $24$.

Now if Order($G$)$=12$, then the number of $2$-sylow subgroups must leave a remainder $1$ when divided by $2$ and it also must divide $3$, hence the number of $2$-sylow subgroups would be $1$, but we already know that the number of $2$-sylow subgroups is at least $2$, hence a contradiction.

So the order($G$)$=24$ (Proved).

Comment: though I prefer not to use Sylow theorems, but that's fine.

Comment: Sylow theorems reveal the structure of the group, it's not bad if you use them, it makes things easy

Comment: Yea, but I would like to pretend not knowing anything about them since they're introduced in later chapters of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Understand what multiplication (from the left) with the given generators means: For the first matrix, it means we add the second row to the first, for the other matrix we add the first row to the second.
Thus the question can be reformulated as follows:

> Given a matrix $M\in SL_2(\Bbb F_3)$, can we transform it into the identity matrix with row addition operations?

To this end, consider a given $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\Bbb F_3)$

If $a=0$, then necessarily $c\ne 0$. Thus by adding the second row to the first if necessary, we may assume that $a\ne 0$.
But then we can add the first row to the second row $-a^{-1}c$ times to obtain $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d'\end{pmatrix}$ with $d'=d-a^{-1}bc$. In fact, from the determinant $1$, we see that $d'=a^{-1}=a$. Now add the second row to the first row $ba$ times to arrive at $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$.
If $a=1$, we are done.

Thus we are only have to deal with $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.
But then we can add the first row to the second row to obtain $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, then add the second to the first to obtain $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$. By the method of the preceding paragraph, this will turn into the identity matrix as this time we start with $a=1$.

---

*Remark:* The above argument works without great changes for any $\Bbb F_p$ (but not $\Bbb F_q$).